# Cling UPnP not returning Actions

Tags: java, android, upnp

I am using [cling UPnP](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/) framework in android to connect to UPnP enabled device. I am successful in creating a device and browsing for available devices in the network. But for the samsung TV in the network the framework in not returning any actions.
Here I am adding the service detail for the RenderingControl

```
<service>
<serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1</serviceType>
<serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl</serviceId>
<controlURL>/upnp/control/RenderingControl1</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/upnp/event/RenderingControl1</eventSubURL>
<SCPDURL>RenderingControl1.xml</SCPDURL>
</service>
```

This is the url for fetching the service descriptor xml file

```
> http://<ip address>:52235/dmr/SamsungMRDesc.xml
```

But the SCPDURL is relative and I am wondering whether the cling framework is searching for

> `http://<ip address>:52235/RenderingControl1.xml`

instead of

> `http://<ip address>:52235/dmr/RenderingControl1.xml`

Is it the reason for no actions being displayed for the services in cling UPnP or am I doing something really stupid?

How can I properly do this with [cling UPnP](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a clarification beforehand: the URL `*SamsungMRDesc.xml` is a *device descriptor*, not a *service descriptor* as you've written, right?

The `<SCPDURL>` per UPnP spec is "relative to the URL at which the device description is located". So yes, the correct absolute SCPDURL is the second one. But i would be highly surprised if there was really such severe bug in Cling. So to offer some theories:

1. What do you mean by "no actions being displayed in Cling UPnP" ? Is that some existing example app or your code? Cling itself does not provide any GUI. Might there be a bug in that code?
2. Are you absolutely sure about the *device descriptor* URL (SamsungMRDesc)? Is it reachable manually, i.e. by simply copy&pasting the URL into web browser?
3. What you see if you copy&paste the SCPDURL into web browser? Are there some `<action>` nodes under `<actionList>`?
4. Have you tried to query your Samsung TV with DeviceSpy from [Intel Developer Tools](http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp) ? You can see what an other UPnP stack sees, besides Cling. Furthermore, you can right-click on a Device node as well as Service node and see where DeviceSpy looks for the descriptions.
5. As a last instance, you can sniff what's being sent back and forth with Wireshark. Start with setting Wireshark IP filter to the address of your Samsung TV.

Theories 4 and 5 obviously require a PC connected to the same network as the TV (and your Android).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For your point 1 : I am using teh sample code provided by cling to discover all UPnP services n the network. While I debug , if I move inside teh identified Device object in debugger console no actions are shown. Its showing an empty list.

Comment: Point 2: Yes I can see the device descriptor URL in browser. For SCPDURL this is not working http://<ip address>:52235/RenderingControl1.xml but this works in a browser http://<ip address>:52235/dmr/RenderingControl1.xml and I can see actionList and actions inside it.

Comment: I just found out that Cling has a standalone application called [Workbench](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/workbench/) which is similar to DeviceSpy. So query your Samsung TV with this Workbench and have a look whether the services and actions are there. If so, you have a problem with your code because Cling apparently does the right thing.

Comment: I found the issue. I was checking the debugger soon after the Cling found the device and before its completely resolved. So that was the issue. Thanks for your help. Intel Developer Tools is really cool.